# need clarification about adding extension to magento

Tags: magento2, magento-connect

i am using Magento 2.0 version,To add extension i need Magento connect under Admin Panel.

After logging in to magento admin panel ,i am not able to get "magento connect" under System module.

So if anybody knows about this things,pls give a reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Connect for Magento 2 yet

You can install Magento 2 extensions with Composer: add an extension's package to the root `composer.json` and then do `composer update` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion ...i will try it...let u know if i face something..